# How to use WP Query to filter posts/pages by slug pattern?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use WP_Query to filter posts by a pattern in slugs.

From the Wordpress reference here:

`https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/`

I have figured that I can filter posts by using `pagename` parameter, but I dont know how can I use a `%like%`  operator to query multiple pages.

I have page slugs setup something like:

```
Fruits/apple
Fruits/banana
Fruits/avocado

Veggies/onion
Veggies/cauliflower
```

What I want is that I need to make use of WP_Query to filter posts based on the following slug patterns:

```
Fruits/%posts
Veggies/%posts
```

How can I modify WP_Query `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'pagename' => 'contact' ) );`  to achieve the desired results?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.